# Eclipse closes automatically

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, slf4j

Eclipse in my Ubuntu 12.10 closes automatically. It happened a lots of time. When I executed eclipse from terminal, it gave me following messages.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
Refresh!!
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
Refresh!!
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
```

I've no idea what is causing this problem.

**What is `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` and how to load it?**

Also if any plugins installed is causing problem, I've installed following plugins.

- WindowsBuilder Pro
- Spring IDE
- EGit
- m2eclipse
- DBViewer
- Dali Java Persistence Tools

I can't put whole **.log** in this question, so I've put it in [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/TheKojuEffect/4996082#file-eclipseautocloseerror-log)

Comment: Please provide error parts from the [`.log` file](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F).

Comment: Did it give you those messages on startup or on exit?

Comment: @jens-na Where can I find .log file?

Comment: @Boann The messages are from full session of eclipse from start to auto close.
The first three lines were shown when starting eclipse.

Comment: I have linked information in my first comment. But you can find it here: `/your/workspace/.metadata/.log`.

Comment: I've added `.log` in question.
If it is hard to read, you can read it from https://gist.github.com/TheKojuEffect/4996082#file-eclipseautocloseerror-log